# Adding delay to the showing of output on if statements in gui Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, visible

I've made this simple code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Nice extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
  JLabel n1 = new JLabel("1");
  JLabel n2 = new JLabel("2");
  JLabel n3 = new JLabel("3");
  JLabel n4 = new JLabel("4");
  JLabel n5 = new JLabel("5");
  JButton show = new JButton("Show The Numbers");

{
    n1.setVisible(false);
    n2.setVisible(false);
    n3.setVisible(false);
    n4.setVisible(false);
    n5.setVisible(false);
}

public Nice(){
super("Timer");
setVisible(true);
setSize(200, 200);
setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
add(n1);
add(n2);         
add(n3);
add(n4);
add(n5);
add(show);
show.addActionListener(this);
   }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
  Object clicked = a.getSource();
  if (show == clicked)
  {
n1.setVisible(true);
n2.setVisible(true);
n3.setVisible(true);
n4.setVisible(true);
n5.setVisible(true);
}
}
}
```

And a class to read it

```
public class NiceOpener{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Nice frame = new Nice();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

However, what I wanted to do was after clicking the show button, instead of setting all the numbers visible at once, it will count for 2 seconds before making another number visible. It's like when I click Show Me it will show 1 then after 2 seconds will show 2 then after 3 seconds will show 3 and so on. What would be the most simpliest way to delay that setting of visible of labels?

Comment: I am not sure but You make the current thread sleep by Thread.sleep(delay), so that i'll stop for sometime

Comment: I tried it but even as i've specified were to put my sleep it sleeps my whole action listener so after I clicked Show Me it waits for the specified number of seconds before showing everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `javax.swing.Timer` .
**UPDATE**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Nice extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
  JLabel n1 = new JLabel("1");
  JLabel n2 = new JLabel("2");
  JLabel n3 = new JLabel("3");
  JLabel n4 = new JLabel("4");
  JLabel n5 = new JLabel("5");
  JButton show = new JButton("Show The Numbers");
  int counter = 1 ;
  boolean started = false;
  javax.swing.Timer timer ;
{
    n1.setVisible(false);
    n2.setVisible(false);
    n3.setVisible(false);
    n4.setVisible(false);
    n5.setVisible(false);
}

public Nice(){
super("Timer");
timer = new javax.swing.Timer(2000,new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
        {
            hideAllLabels();
            if (counter == 1)
            {
                n1.setVisible(true);
                counter++;
            }
            else if (counter == 2)
            {
                n4.setVisible(true);
                counter++;
            }
            else if (counter == 3)
            {
                n2.setVisible(true);
                counter++;
            }
            else if (counter == 4)
            {
                n5.setVisible(true);
                counter++;
            }
            else if (counter == 5)
            {
                n3.setVisible(true);
                counter++;
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    });
timer.setInitialDelay(0);
timer.setDelay(2000);
timer.setRepeats(true);
setVisible(true);setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(200, 200);
setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
add(n1);
add(n2);         
add(n3);
add(n4);
add(n5);
add(show);
show.addActionListener(this);
}
private void hideAllLabels()
{
    n1.setVisible(false);
    n2.setVisible(false);
    n3.setVisible(false);
    n4.setVisible(false);
    n5.setVisible(false);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
  Object clicked = a.getSource();
  if (show == clicked)
  {    
      if (!timer.isRunning())
      {
          if (!started)
          {
            timer.start();
            started = true;
          }
          else
          {
              counter = 1;
              timer.restart();
          }

      }
  }
}
}
public class NiceOpener{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Nice frame = new Nice();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've got a question tho, what if I wanted to randomly pick numbers to make them visible? like 5 first then 2 then 4 then 1 then 3?, oh nvm i figured it out i replace n1 with n5 then so on. If you have any suggestions they are well appreciated thanks

Comment: Nvm I tried replacing n1 with n5 then n3 to n2 then so on but the output was messed up some numbers didn't show up and show numbers stayed visible. If you have an answer i'll be glad to hear about it

Comment: @RusselGo: srry could not get your question.. You want to say that : you want the first delay 5 seconds.. then second delay 3 seconds..and so on..?

Comment: @RusselGo Place the label in an a List and use Math.random() to generate a random number based on the length of the list. Depending on what you need, you could remove each element as you you show it from the list, making it easier

Comment: @Vishal K sorry for the late reply (I was trying different methods to do what I need), My question is what if I want n5 to made visible first then n2 then n3 then n1 then n4. But the catch is that after showing their number, their previous number's visibility will be false. It's like after showing n2, n5's visible will be false. After 2 more seconds it'll show n3 and n2's visibility will be false. After 2 more seconds it'll show n1 and n3's visibility will be false. Then after last 2 more seconds it'll show n4 and n1's visibility will be false.

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry but I want to set a fixed random number, I mean it might look like random numbers from a random user's point of view but from mine its a fixed set of numbers that just aren't in order. Thanks for the reply tho

Comment: I wanna do something like Spring.Rush's answer but in a timer type of method since I really wanna use swing statements to be more familiar with them

Comment: @RusselGo so, instead of using Math.random, add your labels to a List in the "random" order you want. Either pop each of the labels off the top of the list as you need it or maintain an index of the next/current value to use

Comment: @RusselGo: Ok so you mean you want to display the labels randomly.. right?

Comment: @RusselGo Respectively, Spring.Rush's answer might seem easy, but this is by far the better approach

Comment: @VishalK it's something like this http://i48.tinypic.com/2j3mre9.png, after clicking the button on the lower right(sorry forgot to put it in) it will show 1, then after 2 seconds it will show 4, then after 2 seconds it will show 2, then after two seconds it will show 5, then lastly after 2 seconds it will show 3. So I guess it isn't random since I want to set a specific number on each 2 seconds

Comment: @RusselGo: ok let me to go through that image ..and think about ur question then I update my post. .

Comment: @RusselGo: See the updated answer..I guess that this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
    Object clicked = a.getSource();
    if (show == clicked) {
        new ShowTask().start();
    }
}

class ShowTask extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 2;
        n1.setVisible(true);
        try {
            Thread.sleep((i++) * 1000);
            n2.setVisible(true);
            Thread.sleep((i++) * 1000);
            n3.setVisible(true);
            Thread.sleep((i++) * 1000);
            n4.setVisible(true);
            Thread.sleep((i++) * 1000);
            n5.setVisible(true);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should never interact with, modify or create any UI component outside of the context of EDT. This is a bad example

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to achieve what you want.

There are a number of problems you must over come.  The first is, you must never perform any time consuming or blocking actions within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Doing so will, amongst other things, prevent Swing from processing repaint requests.

The second is, you must never, ever, create or modify any UI component from any thread other then EDT.

The simplest approach is to use a `javax.swing.Timer`.  Another means is by using a `SwingWorker`.

The following example provides a means by which you can define a pseudo random order.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLabelDelay extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                TestLabelDelay frame = new TestLabelDelay();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    private List<JLabel> labels;

    public TestLabelDelay() {
        super("Timer");
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        labels = new ArrayList<>(25);
        for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
            labels.add(createLabel(index));
        }

        add(labels.get(0));
        add(labels.get(1));
        add(labels.get(2));
        add(labels.get(3));
        add(labels.get(4));

        JButton show = new JButton("Show");
        add(show);
        show.addActionListener(this);
    }

    protected JLabel createLabel(int index) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(String.valueOf(index));
        label.setVisible(false);
        return label;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        List<Integer> order = new ArrayList<>(5);
        order.add(2);
        order.add(4);
        order.add(0);
        order.add(3);
        order.add(1);

        new ShowWorker(labels, order).execute();
    }

    public class ShowWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

        private List<JLabel> labels;
        private List<Integer> order;

        private ShowWorker(List<JLabel> labels, List<Integer> order) {
            this.labels = labels;
            this.order = order;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
            for (Integer index : chunks) {
                JLabel label = labels.get(order.get(index));
                label.setVisible(true);
                label.repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int index = 0; index < labels.size(); index++) {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                publish(index);
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks alot though I need to review everything you've inputted as to help me understand this code better for future uses. Thanks